# following login form tutorial - not working

Tags: php, symfony

In the Book for symfony2 on pages 156-157 There is a nice tutorial for how to make your own login system using forms.

When I follow these steps, I am faced with a "No route found for "POST /login_check"" error message.

security.yml:

```
secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/secured/
    form_login:
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /secured/login_check
    logout:
        path:   /secured/logout
        target: /login
```

routing.yml:

```
login:
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: MySecurityBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
    pattern: /secured/login_check
```

Can anyonw tell me why mine doesn't work and sensioLabs apparently does?

The only difference I can see is that I wiped out the Acme bundle and created a fresh bundle with security, copy-pasting all files as per tutorial (I thought ACME was a demo bundle and not necessary for functions such as security?).

I have no default route set for the login_check route, since tutorial says on page 156 "You will not need to implement a controller for the /login_check URL as the firewall will
automatically catch and process any form submitted to this URL."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify controller but you have to specify routing path, in your case it is

```
pattern: /secured/login_check
```

but you are submitting form to `/login_check`, edit either yor form action to include `/secure` or remove it from routing.yml